# Converting DOCX to HTML without MS Office

Tags: .net, html, docx

Is there a .NET component which can convert docx to HTML (e.g. as per Word->SaveAs->HTMLPage) but without MS Office installed?

Comment: Does it have to b a .NET component? There's OpenOffice that can do it, runs on Windows and has a headless mode (i.e. is usable from the command line)

Comment: This is answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824619/batch-conversion-of-docx-to-clean-html

Comment: `Mammoth.js https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js` can be a good option for basic conversion

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Aspose.Words](http://www.aspose.com/categories/.net-components/aspose.words-for-.net/default.aspx).

Their library allows converting between various documents formats, including DOC/DOCX to HTML via code. They have a very intuitive and simple API, and are very active in their development and improvements of their libraries.

Comment: Do you know any similar tools ? I need the opposite way , HTML To Docx / PDF. But aspose words is to expensive for the budget i got from my boss

Comment: I'm not familiar with specific HTML to PDF libraries, though I'm sure there are a few. HTML to DOCX can be created on your own if your would like to save money (at the price of writing your own code) - you just have to learn the DOCX language....

Answer (score 0):

You may want to make use of Mammoth docx to HTML library, its 7 year too late, it seems :) but anyways its a library for displaying doc, docx documents by converting them to html on the browser side as well as can be handled on the backend.

- Library Supports - JavaScript, both the browser and node.js. Available on npm.
  Python. Available on PyPI.
  WordPress.
  Java/JVM. Available on Maven Central.
  .NET. Available on NuGet.
- Link: https://mike.zwobble.org/projects/mammoth/ (Demo and Article)
- Github: https://github.com/mwilliamson/mammoth.js